# My model's loss value decreases slowly .how to reduce my loss faster while training?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, nlp

when I train the model the loss decrease from 0.9 to 0.5 in 2500 epochs. Is it normal?

my model:

```
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Embedding(vocab_size , emd_dim, weights=[emd_matrix], input_length=maxLen,trainable=False))

    model.add(LSTM(256,return_sequences=True,activation="relu",kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_normal(seed=None)))
    model.add(LSTM(256,return_sequences=True,activation="relu",kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_normal(seed=None)))

    model.add(LSTM(256,return_sequences=False,activation="relu",kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_normal(seed=None)))
    model.add(Dense(l_h2i,activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
    filepath = "F:/checkpoints/"+modelname+"/lstm-{epoch:02d}-{loss:0.3f}-{acc:0.3f}-{val_loss:0.3f}-{val_acc:0.3f}.hdf5"
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor="loss", verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
    reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', factor=0.5, patience=2, min_lr=0.000001)
    print(model.summary())
    history=model.fit(X_train_indices, Y_train_oh, batch_size=batch_size ,
                      epochs=epochs , validation_split=0.1, shuffle=True,
                      callbacks=[checkpoint, reduce_lr])
```

some part of the results are as shown here :

```
loss improved from 0.54275 to 0.54272
loss: 0.5427 - acc: 0.8524 - val_loss: 1.1198 - val_acc: 0.7610

loss improved from 0.54272 to 0.54268
loss: 0.5427 - acc: 0.8525 - val_loss: 1.1195 - val_acc: 0.7311

loss improved from 0.54268 to 0.54251
loss: 0.5425 - acc: 0.8519 - val_loss: 1.1218 - val_acc: 0.7420

loss improved from 0.54251 to 0.54249
loss: 0.5425 - acc: 0.8517 - val_loss: 1.1210 - val_acc: 0.7518
```

Comment: did you managed to solve the problem? I'm also having the same issue

Comment: Not yet, I am struggling with some other kind of issues and would appreciate it if you share your solution with me whenever you achieve it. @basilisk

Answer (score 0):

consider updating ReduceLROnPlateau parameters as in [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ReduceLROnPlateau). Factor should be a larger and Patience should be smaller numbers

```
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2,
                              patience=5, min_lr=0.001)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, callbacks=[reduce_lr])
```

**Arguments:**

> - monitor: quantity to be monitored.
> - **factor**: factor by which the learning rate will be reduced. new_lr = lr * factor
> - **patience**: number of epochs with no improvement after which learning rate will be    reduced.
> - verbose: int. 0: quiet, 1: update messages.
> - mode: one of {auto, min, max}. In min mode, lr will be reduced when the quantity    monitored has stopped decreasing; in max mode it will
>     be reduced when the quantity     monitored has stopped increasing; in
>     auto mode, the direction is automatically     inferred from the name
>     of the monitored quantity.
> - min_delta: threshold for measuring the new optimum, to only    focus on significant changes.
> - cooldown: number of epochs to wait before resuming normal operation after lr has been     reduced.
> - min_lr: lower bound on the learning rate.

Comment: I changed it as you said but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: can you set min_lr=.01 and try again

Comment: It did not change the condition either.